# line integration. integrate work

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

I taught line integration by myself. My textbook provide me two definition of line integration to integrate vector field.

1. $\int^a_bf(x(t),y(t))\sqrt{(x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}dt$
2. $\int^a_b \vec F(\vec r(t))\cdot \vec r'(t)dt$

I try to use the first definition to calculate a problem from my textbook

> F(x,y) = $xy(i)+3y^2(j)$,
>   r(t) = $11t^4(i)+t^3(j)$ ,$0<t<1$

my calculation:
I consider x as $11t^4$, y as $t^3$ and then get
$\int^1_0 (11t^3)(t^3)+3(t^3)\sqrt{44t^3+3t^2}dt$
however, the answer is wrong. Can anyone tell me what's the wrong with my calculation?

Comment: Is the integrand in $2$ the scalar product of $\vec F$ with $d\vec r$?  If so, then it is not the same type of line integral as that in $1$.

Comment: why aren't they the same? I'm new to this topic...

Comment: The first is $\int f |d\vec r|$ and the second is $\int \vec F \cdot \vec dr$